# Could I say "an obvious pitfall"?

Tags: word-usage

From the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pitfall):

> [image]

The definition above said it is **not obvious**, but the example sentence used **obvious pitfall**, is it odd?

Comment: "the most obvious pitfalls" sounds OK to me in British English, but if you think it is an oxymoron you could say "the most common pitfalls".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary, "pitfall" can take any of the following adjectives:

- obvious
- common
- hidden
- possible
- potential

Notice that the definition says that the danger or difficulty is usually not obvious **at first**, and the second example presents the need to rely on professional advice to avoid pitfalls which, even if obvious to experts, may not be so evident to the layman.

[image: Here is the reference I mentioned above:]

Answer (score 5):

The definition also says **especially** one that is hidden or not obvious, the base meaning is still **a danger or difficulty**.

Obvious pitfall sounds natural enough to me.

Answer (score 4):

Even though *pitfalls* are not obvious by nature, among such pitfalls they could be rated as more or less obvious.
In this sense, you can have most/more/less/least obvious pitfalls.

Comment: Exactly. If you have fifty midgets, some of them will be among the tallest midgets.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a difference in perspective in the meaning of "obvious" in the two sentences:

> a danger or difficulty, especially one that is hidden or not obvious at first

That is, not obvious to the person about to fall into it.

> Getting professional advice will help you avoid the most obvious pitfalls

That is, obvious to *me*, the person telling *you* to get advice. The pitfall will not be obvious to you - that's why you should get advice, to discover what it is. (At which point, it's obvious, and hence, not a pitfall anymore. Which hopefully helps you avoid it. :))